# WordPress 3.0.1 Query Custom Post Type with Custom Taxonomy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I have a custom post type with multiple taxonomy types. The issue is focused around just one of them.
I need to display all custom posts that have a taxonomy from featured-vendors checked. Right now, there is just one "featured" , but there may be more in the future, such as "highlight" or "sponsor" or something alone those lines.
But, for now, I just need to go through all the "vendors" custom post type, find ones with "featured" checked inside of the "featured-vendors" taxonomy.

I have some some posts out there that state it's not possible, but they were either from 2.8 or from the very first of this year and I know WordPress has released at least one update since then.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Query Custom Post Types by Taxonomy Term

This sample will assume:

- the custom post type was registered with the taxonomy and the taxonomy was registerd with `'query_var' =>true`  and `'hierarchial' => true`
- The "checked" term will be the **parent** and any new ones can be added later on as **children.**

### The Code:

```
 <?php query_posts( array( 'featured-vendors' => 'checked' ) ); ?>
    <?php if( is_tax() ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $term = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $title = $term->name;
    }  ?>
    
    <div class="my-custom-post">
    <h3><?php echo($title); ?></h3> //this will show the name of the post type
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    
     <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> 

    <div class="entry"> <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

        <?php the_excerpt(); ?> //shows the excerpt 

     </div><!--/end entry-->
</div><!--/end post-->
    
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('No Post Found','your_theme_text_domain'); ?></p> 

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot and see what it comes up with!